# sstableloader copying data N replica times

Tags: cassandra

When using SSTableLoader to load SSTables of size 'N' MBs into a keyspace setup with 3 replicas, the tool transfers '3N' MBs of data from the machine where the SSTables reside to the C* cluster. Similarly, twice the amount of data was getting transferred when I was loading to a keyspace with 2 replicas. I confirmed this by looking into network activity as well.

I have left the configs to be default. Is there a way to enforce the tool to copy only once and let the data get replicated on the C* cluster instead of copying N(replica) number of times? Network transfer is expensive for us.

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to move. Could you please let me know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as advertised. The `sstableloader` utility works in a completely different way compared to Cassandra clients.

In an "ordinary" client/driver setup where an application issues a write request, the driver (1) picks a coordinator for the request, (2) sends the mutation to the coordinator, then (3) the coordinator forwards the mutation to all the replicas in the cluster.

In contrast, the `sstableloader` (4) splits the SSTable(s) into chunks that map to a token range, then (5) streams the parts of the SSTable to the replicas that own them.

The major difference is that `sstableloader` (6) does *not* send individual mutations to a coordinator -- (7) it streams SSTable fragments which contain multiple partitions to the replicas. This means that (8) bulk-loading with `sstableloader` does *not* follow the regular write path. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much Erick! Is it the case with nodetool import (https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/bulk_loading.html#using-nodetool-import) as well?

We are looking to move 30+ TBs of data (JSON or SSTables) from one datacenter to another. So, egress is kind of expensive for us. At the same time we would want to move as soon as possible. Based on some tests bulk-load seems to happen pretty quick for us. Do you have any recommendations for how to achieve this?

Comment: We're glad to help! We do request that you create a new post for new questions. The comments section is reserved exactly for that -- comments.  If we keep answering questions in the comments section, it will be a never-ending thread. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick. Posted a question. Please help when you get a chance - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325917/moving-huge-amount-30-tb-daily-of-data-from-aws-to-on-prem-cassandra-cluster